# Atualizar vários IDs ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Como atualizar vários registros ao mesmo tempo apenas com um click com php/mysql?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tu queres saber como fica o update? Se sim, tente fazer dessa forma: `update tabela set campo = 'valor' where id in ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')`.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno nesse caso ele irá atualizar todos os id's com o mesmo valor, no exemplo que ele deu cada ID recebe um valor diferente. Penso que ele irá precisar de utilizar multi-query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Verdade, realmente não tinha notado esse detalhe no exemplo.

Comment: Dependendo da estrutura da tabela, normalmente prefiro usar o REPLACE INTO, o qual suporta, numa única query, múltiplos valores, tal como funciona no INSERT. É mais performático do que fazer vários updates ou mesmo usar o multi_query do mysqli.   Não vou comentar sobre o envio dos dados para o PHP. Acho que pelo menos , o básico do HTML vc deve saber..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você irá atualizar o campo com o mesmo valor para todos os id's, basta utilizar o exemplo do Jéferson Bueno (nos comentários):

```
update tabela set campo = 'valor' where id in ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')
```

Se cada id receber um valor diferente, você irá precisar de utilizar [multi-query.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

**Exemplo**:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* verifica conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "update tabela set campo = 'Novo_a2' where id='id1';";
$query .= "update tabela set campo = 'Novo_c2' where id='id3';";
$query .= "update tabela set campo = 'Novo_d2' where id='id4';";

/* executa a sua multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* Faz print separado do resultado de cada query */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* separa cada resultado por traços */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* fecha conexão */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```